# is there any good resource for video lectures of differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am wondering if there is some online resource for video lectures on the topic of differential geometry.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Not quite a mathematical question.

Comment: That would help a lot of student. I know this site http://www.math.ncsu.edu/mmc/videotape.php but there there is no DG.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Clay Mathematics Institute 2005 Summer School on Ricci Flow, 3 Manifolds And Geometry* generously provided [video](http://www.msri.org/web/msri/scientific/workshops/summer-graduate-workshops/show/-/event/Wm367) recordings of the lectures that are extremely useful for differential geometry students.

In fact, MSRI Online Videos is [enormous](http://www.msri.org/web/msri/online-videos), and their [archive](http://www.msri.org/realvideo/index2.html) has some interesting parts [for DG students] (not quite sure if they still work, though).

I am not mentioning Youtube here but if you are interested in elementary topics you may find some useful videos there.

Comment: This [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/396686/2002) provides a very useful [video course](http://www.youtube.com/user/justinmsolomon?feature=watch) on Youtube

Comment: In order to watch or download the videos by Clay Mathematics Institute, do I have to register there or I can access it without doing so?

Answer (score 6):

A rather late answer, but for anyone finding this via search: MSRI is currently (Spring 2016) hosting a program on [Differential Geometry](http://www.msri.org/programs/286) that has/will have extensive video of all lectures given in the related workshops (Connections for Women, Introductory Workshop on Modern Riemannian Geometry, Kähler Geometry, Einstein Metrics, and Generalizations, and Geometric Flows in Riemannian and Complex Geometry). Scroll down to the schedule at the bottom of the page, click through to the workshop pages, and you will see a video link to watch each talk listed.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent resource, a course offered by Stanford for people from different background, not just for the mathematicians. So you can grasp it even with some basic maths.
[Differential Geometry for Computer Science](https://cosmolearning.org/courses/differential-geometry-for-computer-science/video-lectures/)

Comment: A newer course with much better recording can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQ3UicqQtfNtUcdTMLgKSTTOiEsCw2VBW).  The instructor (now at MIT) specifically mentions that it covers the same materials as the original Differential Geometry course (mentioned [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhNZ63URUzA&list=PLQ3UicqQtfNvPmZftPyQ-qK1wdXBxj86W&index=3) in the comments)

Answer (score 1):

Frederic Schuller's "[**Lectures on the Geometrical Anatomy of Theoretical Physics**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V49i_LM8B0E&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic)" are superb. Someone has also written up [lecture notes](https://mathswithphysics.blogspot.com/2016/07/lectures-on-geometric-anatomy-of.html) from the videos.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's in the applied context, there is a person named Frederic Schuller who has made mathematically rigorous lectures on Differential Geometry beginning only at logic. Here it [is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V49i_LM8B0E&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic).