# Differential Geometry Video Lectures

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, manifolds, online-resources

I know there's a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140126/is-there-any-good-resource-for-video-lectures-of-differential-geometry), however since what I found there wasn't what I was looking for I thought on creating a new question. I'm studying Differential Geometry through Spivak's book "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry Vol. 1" and I'm looking for video lectures on differential geometry at this level (introduction to the analysis on manifolds and so on).

Until now I didn't find any video lectures. The only ones I've founded related to that are the one in the question I've mentioned, however that's too advanced for now. There are any good video lectures on this introductory (but yet rigorous) Differential Geometry? And I've pointed the rigorous part because I've found some videos on youtube, however the ones I've found simply ignore rigorous aspects of the subject and do things too loosely (even without defining manifolds properly).

Thanks very much in advance and sorry if this question is somehow silly!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there any good resource for video lectures of differential geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140126/is-there-any-good-resource-for-video-lectures-of-differential-geometry)

Answer (score 8):

[Differential Geometry for Computer Science](http://www.youtube.com/user/justinmsolomon?feature=watch) is the best I can find.